# How to stop automated "Approaching SharePoint Site Storage Limit" emails in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, storage-quota

I'm using **SharePoint Online** keep getting automated emails for hundreds of SharePoint Online sites (Team Sites with no group attached) that I administer stating that the sites are approaching their SharePoint site storage limit when in reality the storage used on these sites is 5% or less of the limit?

Is there anyway to stop these emails being sent? (not interested in getting an email unless storage use > 70%).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the Active sites page of the new [SharePoint admin center](https://admin.microsoft.com/sharepoint?page=siteManagement&modern=true), and sign in with an account that has admin permissions for your organization.
2. Select a site, and then select **Storage**.

[image]

3. Enter the maximum storage in GB for the site.
4. Make sure **Notifications** is turned on to send an email to site admins when the site approaches the storage limit. Then, enter a value as a percent for how full you want the storage to be when the email is sent.
5. Select **Save**.

Reference https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/manage-site-collection-storage-limits#set-automatic-or-manual-site-storage-limits

Comment: Thanks for this, for all these sites I have Allow Notifications unchecked, therefore you think I would not get any emails but I still do.